# How can I make a choice field with steps in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to make something like the image below. Let's say that I have 3 multiple choice fields like the following. If I choose `bags` from `choices_first`, I want `choices_for_bags` to show up as the next choice step.

The below image is one of the fields for Django default user model. It's for another purpose. I'm looking for something like that. As I choose something on the left, I want something to show up on the right based on the choice on the left. Does Django admin provide anything like that as default or is there any library for that?

```
choices_first = (
            ('clothing', 'Clothing'),
            ('bags', 'Bags'),
        )

choices_for_clothing = (
            ('tops', 'Tops'),
            ('bottoms', 'Bottoms'),
        )

choices_for_bags = (
            ('handbags', 'Handbags'),
            ('backpacks', 'Backpacks'),
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know **django-smart-selects** provide ***[ChainedManyToManyField](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#chained-manytomany-selects)*** option which should be similar to User Permissions scenario since its ManyToMany field, but I'm not sure if it will work as you need.